# Database design, how to normalize?

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

I am currently struggling with creating a proper database scheme design for my project. Let me introduce the tables:

**tblOrder**

```
id
executive_id
supervisor_id
client_id
building_id?
```

**tblexecutive**

```
executive_id
address_id
```

**tblsupervisor**

```
supervisor_id
address_id
```

**tblclient**

```
client_id
address_id
```

**tbladdress**

```
generic information, e.g location phone fax
```

Not sure about this one:

**tblbuilding**

```
building_id
address_id
( or address information here )
```

This looks quite normalized to me. But a client gives a building where an order is performed which also is associated with an address. Is it proper to refer to the address table or to create a new building table with addresses or to add a new address table field, e.g. isOrderBuilding (bool)?

Comment: What does "looks quite normalized" mean? Whatever you mean, clearly it's not "is normalized". Read the references you were given. Google 'normalization': online there are many .ppt & .pdf slides (eg from universities utexas.edu, stanford.edu & sfu.ca) and even textbooks (eg Maier's).

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the real world, a building might have more then one address.
Think of corner buildings, they have 2 addresses.
What if the building is so big that it covers a hole block?
this requires at 4 different addresses for a single building.
To cope with this, I would suggest having a building id in your address table, so that each address will reference a single building, but any building could have multiple addresses.

However, it is quite possible that you don't need that in your project, and a single address is sufficient for each building. 
If that is the case, then I suggest keeping the buildings and the addresses in a single table.

Any way, for the address itself I suggest to break it to at least 3 tables:
Cities table, Streets table, and Address table (with the appropriate relationships). Also, you can go down even deeper and create a Streets To Cities relationship table, and have the Address table relate to this table instead. 
This will prevent you from specifying addresses on streets that doesn't belong to the city of that address.

Again, this all depends on the project needs. my last suggestion is probably an overkill if it's just a school project, but if it's for a commercial grade software I would definitely use it.